# Redirect() throws a blank page.working fine in my localhost.

Tags: php, redirect

Redirect() throws a blank page.But working fine in my localhost. 
I tried using :

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=xyz.php">
```

This works fine.But i need redirect function to work properly...

My code is :

```
redirect("index.php");
```

Comment: Redirect is no standard function delivered by php. Use `header("Location: index.php");`.

Comment: Sorry,not to mention that redirect function is defined manually. It's converted to header("Location: index.php").But it's not working.

Comment: Post the function if you defined the function manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `header("Location: /index.php");`, assuming that the index.php file is located in the root of the site.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Also note that this would probably work too `header("Location: /");` since index.php is the default file a server looks for in the site root.

Finally, the reason for the blank page is most likely because redirect is not a valid function in php ;)

Comment: Sorry,not to mention that redirect function is defined manually. It's converted to header("Location: index.php").But it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And does the slash in front of index make any difference?

Comment: Also, if there is any kind of echo/print/var_dump before the redirect, header() will fail. Did you know this already?